Kotlin Compose smooth scrolling of all pages in the HorizontalPager
How can I achieve smooth scrolling of all pages, let's say from 1 to 30. Scrolling jumps over all the intermediate pages, up to 28, then smoothly jumps to 30
pagerState.animateScrollToPage(30, animationSpec = tween(5000))

To achieve a truly smooth scrolling animation across all pages, you can incrementally scroll through each page with small delays in between.
Incremental Page Scroll with Coroutine:
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerState
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
suspend fun smoothScrollThroughPages(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    targetPage: Int,
    delayMillis: Long = 100, // Delay between pages
    animationDuration: Int = 300 // Duration for each page animation
) {
    val currentPage = pagerState.currentPage

    if (currentPage < targetPage) {
        for (page in currentPage until targetPage) {
            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page + 1, animationSpec = tween(animationDuration))
            delay(delayMillis) // Small delay to ensure smoothness
        }
    } else if (currentPage > targetPage) {
        for (page in currentPage downTo targetPage + 1) {
            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(page - 1, animationSpec = tween(animationDuration))
            delay(delayMillis) // Small delay to ensure smoothness
        }
    }
}

Usage Example
 val scope = rememberCoroutineScope() 
   val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
   
    scope.launch {
        smoothScrollThroughPages(pagerState, targetPage = 30, delayMillis = 100, animationDuration = 300) 
        }

